# What will be specific benchmark of elasticsearch reads, writes and updates?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

We are using Elasticsearch (version 5.6.0) data updates of around 13M documents with each document in the nested structure having max 100 key value pair, it takes around 34 min to update 99 indices. Hardware is as follows:

- 5 M4-4x large machines (32G RAM and 8 cores)
- 500GB disk

So, what should be the Ideal update time elasticsearch should take for the update?

What are the optimization I can do to get good performance?

Comment: You will probably need to show your specific example if you want tuning tips - it is likely to depend on your specific case. Is there any such thing as an explain plan in Elasticsearch? If so, add that to your question too.

Comment: So their is no specific plan. We have cluster with no specific data nodes or master nodes . Simple cluster were all 5 nodes are  data nodes and anyone can be master . Any specific you want to know?